# How to execute the python code with package in cmd?

Tags: python, import, package

```
project
    __init__.py
    module_1
    module_2

    test_pkg
        __init__.py
        test_module_1  ----> import module_1 
        test_module_2  ----> import module_2
```

I'm using the above structure and It is running fine in eclipse IDE. But I cannot run from the command prompt.

normal python module can be executed as below,

```
python test_code.py
```

But while I run the test_module_1 or test_module_2 shows below error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_module_1.py", line 8, in <module>
    from project.module_1 import module_1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_1'
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you running the command prompt in the same directory as your project/module?

Comment: Yes @Mohit Motwani

Comment: Is this python2 or python3?

Comment: It is python3.6.5 @Blinxen

Comment: Try running `python3 -m test.test_module_1` on `project` directory

Comment: Tried 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. If I use python -m test.test_module_1.py same ModuleNotFoundError occuring @kavinvin